# How to use like numbers on string by mongodb

Tags: mongodb, numbers, sql-like

I have collection that contain field seen that store numbers as string
for example seen = '13,12,15'

now when I use 'like' query to collection where number like 2 
Example

```
db.notification.find({seen :/2/})
```

result will get all collection that seen have numbers 12 and 2 and 122

I need query to get collections that have number 2 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your immediate problem (using word-boundary character)

```
db.notification.find({seen: /\b2\b/})
```

But you really should be storing numbers as numbers, and not concatenated string. Much of the pain of working with mongodb comes from poorly designed data schema. Your question is a perfect example of this.

Comment: thanks for you replay but I tried this query db.notification.find({seen: /\b2\b/}) but it return me number 12 , I know storing data as  concatenated string is poor but I have data and I can't change it for now

Comment: you mean seen string ?  "seen" : "12,53,2,98" that's what get when execute your query

Comment: yes I tried it again and it work fine 
Thank you  :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use below for your result using $regex

```
db.notification.find({seen:{ $regex: /2/}})
```